# detached entity when using ManyToMany in jpa 2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, jpa-2.1

I'm creating an app and I have a ManyToMany relation between `Recipe` and `Ingredients`,
but when I'm trying to insert new row in `RecipeIngredient` using JPA 2.1 i got :

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist.

This is my entities : 
`

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@CrossCheck
public class Ingredient implements ValidEntity {

static final String PREFIX = "com.architech.sales.ingredient.entity.";
public static final String FIND_ALL = PREFIX + "FIND_ALL";
public static final String FIND_BY_ID = PREFIX + "FIND_BY_ID";

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@NotNull
private String label;
private String description;

// added just to reply to @Maciej-Kowalski
@OneToMany(targetEntity = RecetteIngredient.class, mappedBy = "ingredient")
private List<RecetteIngredient> recetteIngredients;

@Version
private long version;
// Getter / Setter

}
```

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@CrossCheck
public class Recette implements ValidEntity{

static final String PREFIX = "sales.recette.entity.Recette.";
public static final String FIND_ALL = PREFIX + "FIND_ALL";
public static final String FIND_BY_ID = PREFIX + "FIND_BY_ID";

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Size(min = 1, max = 256)
private String label;
private String description;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = RecetteIngredient.class, mappedBy = "recette")
private List<RecetteIngredient> recetteIngredients;

@Version
private long version;

// Getter/Setter
}
`
```

`

```
@Entity
@IdClass(RecetteIngredientPK.class)
public class RecetteIngredient implements Serializable{

@Id
private long id;
private double qte;

@Id
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Ingredient.class)
private Ingredient ingredient;

@Id
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Recette.class)
private Recette recette;

// Getter/Setter
}
`
```

and my persistence unit

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="prod" transaction-type="JTA">
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <!--<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />-->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>`

This is the stacktrace :

`

```
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.architech.sales.ingredient.entity.Ingredient
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.merge(AbstractEntityManager.java:565)
    at com.architech.sales.recette_ingredient.boundary.RecetteIngredientManager.save(RecetteIngredientManager.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
`
```

and this is how i'm trying to persiste RecetteIngredient :

```
`
@Stateless
@Interceptors(BoundaryLogger.class)
public class RecetteIngredientManager {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public RecetteIngredient findById(long id) {
    return this.em.find(RecetteIngredient.class, id);
}

public void delete(long id) {
    try {
        RecetteIngredient reference = this.em.getReference(RecetteIngredient.class, id);
        this.em.remove(reference);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        //we want to remove it...
    }
}

public RecetteIngredient save(RecetteIngredient recetteIngredient) {
    return this.em.merge(recetteIngredient);
}

}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your linking class add merge cascade option on the `@ManyToOne` mappings:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(RecetteIngredientPK.class)
public class RecetteIngredient implements Serializable{

@Id
private long id;
private double qte;

@Id
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Ingredient.class, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private Ingredient ingredient;

@Id
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Recette.class, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private Recette recette;
```

This will advise the PersistenceContext to merge also the Ingredient and Recette entities if they happen to be detached at the time.

If you are not allowed to change the annotations then you would have to persist / merge Ingredient and Recette entities manually before persising the linking table:

```
public RecetteIngredient save(RecetteIngredient recette) {
  this.em.merge(recette.getIngredient());
  this.em.merge(recette.getRecette());

  return this.em.merge(recette);
}
```

Of course this is a workaround and the first approach is definately more elegant and advisable.

Comment: thank you for your reply,
i have tested the both solutions but still getting the same error.

Comment: try adding persist cascade also - cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}

Comment: i even tried 'cascade = CascadeType.ALL' and still getting the same error,

Comment: On the Ingredient entity try to add @OneToMany mapping as you did on Recette. In theory its not needed but give it a try

Comment: I aded @OneToamny as you recommanded, now i got another error "Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.architech.sales.ingredient.entity.Ingredient.recetteIngredients, could not initialize proxy - no Session"

Comment: i'm very thankful to your replies, i edited my poste by including the @OneToMany in Ingredient, and i have added the RecetteIngredientManager.

Comment: Ok try to add @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.Required) to the RecetteIngredientManager definition. If nothing changes add it on the save method

Comment: Ok it seems that there is something wrong with transaction configuration. Can perform any other entitymanager operations like em.find(Ingredient.class, 1); etc.?

Comment: yes all crud operations works on ingredient and recette.

Comment: Can run em.find(RecetteIngredient.class, id)?

Comment: i think there is some things that is missed in my persistence.xml

Comment: yes it runs succefully, but the table is empty, so i get no result.

Comment: is very strange a replaced hibernate by eclipselink and it solved my problemes

Comment: Ok did you use any of my tips or the orignial this.em.merge(recette); was enough without any other stuff?

Comment: no i revert all modification i remove the merge of entities, even (, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
and it work, i think is some thing wrong in wildFly or hibernate with jpa 2.1 and JAVA EE 7

Comment: Thank you @maciej-kowalski and i will inform you if know the reason, or whats wrong in my code

Comment: Welcome. If you think any of my tips added some value to you i would appreciate if you would add your up vote.